# gnu cut remove everything from :

Tags: cut

I am trying to clean up a set of ipv6 ip addresses.

```
cat /tmp/ipaddress.txt | /bin/grep -i "unexpectedly shrunk window" | /bin/cut -d' ' -f3 | /bin/cut -d'/' -f1 | /bin/cut -d' ' -f3 | /bin/sort --uniq > /var/log/dos_ip6.txt
```

/tmp/ipaddress.txt contains the following

```
TCP: Peer 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:4df6:3e12:12345/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 1550831482:1550831483 (repaired)
```

/var/log/dos_ip6.txt contains the following

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:4df6:3e12:12345
```

i would like to cut the last "*:12345" out.

How can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your thinking of using two or more `cut` commands, perhaps consider using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1 } { print gensub(/(.*):.*/, "\\1", "g", $3) | "sort -u" }' /tmp/ipaddress.txt
```

Result:

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:4df6:3e12
```

---

Otherwise, a simple pipe to `sed` should suffice:

```
... | sed 's/\(.*\):.*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, but if we want to do this using `cut` alone, we can do something like this:

```
echo "TCP: Peer 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:4df6:3e12:12345/80 unexpectedly shrunk window 1550831482:1550831483 (repaired)"| cut -d" " -f3| cut -d":" -f1-8
```

This will result in:

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:4df6:3e12
```